# WatchOS 2 Flurry integration

Tags: ios, flurry, watchos-2

I can't compile WatchOS 2 project with Flurry framework. (Xcode 7.1)

[image]

For now WatchOS SDK hasn't SystemConfiguration.framework.

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flurry doesn't have support for Watch OS2 yet. We are working on it for a future SDK release.